# PHP: YouTube Data API v3 rejecting my request

Tags: php, youtube, httprequest, http-status-code-403, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get title and description from an YouTube video using Youtube Data API v3. I've written a simple function to do so:

```
function get_data_from_yt($yt_id) {
    $key = YT_API_KEY;
    $yt_id = urlencode($yt_id);

    $data_string = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=$yt_id&key=$key&part=snippet");
    $data = json_decode($data_string, true);

    return $data;
}
```

The problem is when I try to use this function, it gives me this error

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=7Wj_q7HBP48&key=MY_API_KEY&part=snippet): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
```

I have an IP limitation set on my API key, but I added my serwer's IP to the whitelist. I also added my computer IP and tried opening this link with my browser, and it worked. Also when I turn key limitations off, whole thing works perfectly.

I don't want to leave my key not secured because of obvious reasons, but I don't know how to get over this issue. Help would be very appreciated.

I'll provide futher information if needed.